# API Gateway custom authorizer mystery 503

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway set up to use a lambda as its custom authorizer. The majority of requests pass through the authorizer successfully, and I can also see expected `Unauthorized` failures (which API Gateway returns as 401s) for requests which lack a token or have a bad token.

My problem is a small number of unexplained API errors, which are logged like:

```
(example-api-request-id) Starting authorizer: some-id for request: some-uuid
(example-api-request-id) Incoming identity: ***********************
(example-api-request-id) Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:redacted:function:redacted:production/invocations
(example-api-request-id) Endpoint request headers: [TRUNCATED]
(example-api-request-id) Endpoint request body after transformations: {"type":"TOKEN","methodArn":"arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:redacted:redacted/production/GET/some_path","authorizationToken":"some-valid-token"}
(example-api-request-id) Sending request to https://lambda.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:redacted:function:redacted:production/invocations
(example-api-request-id) Lambda invocation failed with status: 503. Lambda request id: example-lambda-request-id
(example-api-request-id) Execution failed due to configuration error: Authorizer error
```

As far as I can see, that is the full lifecycle of one of these bad requests - there are no more entries for `example-api-request-id`.

If I go and search the authorizer lambda logs for `example-lambda-request-id`, there are no entries at all, not even `START RequestId: example-lambda-request-id`.

What am I seeing here? How can I go about debugging these errors?

Comment: if your authorizer doesn't have any logs, then your business function shouldn't be invoked as well, in this case maybe the Gateway is rejecting the API calls for some reason, HTTP 503 Status Code (Service Unavailable) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-503-service-unavailable.html